# Resizing centered responsive img while maintaining the container's size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hqew7zkJ8PrKoiZtA6ju?p=preview) example, the left (yellow) cell is the relevant one. It isn't bootstrap-specific but I've used its classes to make the image responsive.

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6" style="padding:30px; background:yellow">
    <div class="wrapper">
    <img class="center-block img-responsive" style="position: absolute" src="..."">
    <img class="center-block img-responsive" style="visibility: hidden" src="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6" style="padding:30px; background:lime">
    <img class="center-block img-responsive" src="...">
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

And relevant css, borrowed from bootstrap

```
.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  width:90%;
  height: auto;
}

.img-responsive:hover {
  min-width:110%;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%; 
}
```

The thing I'm trying to accomplish:

- Fit the image into the container (bootstrap column with some padding here) proportionally **(ok)**
- Make it a bit smaller while keeping it at center, container's size is unchanged **(ok)**
- Make it bigger on hover while still keeping it at center, container's size is unchanged **(fixed with `transform: scale`)**
- The second layered image (absolute-positioned) should fit the size and the position of the first **(not ok)**

I've made placeholder`<img>` hidden to keep the container's size, but `<img>` with `position: absolute` aligns to the left anyway.

How this can be solved? I will use JS on page but clearly I'm not eager to use it to pin that image to the placeholder programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make it bigger on hover while still keeping it at center, container's size is unchanged**
Use CSS3's transform attribute :

```
.img-responsive:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Make sure to prefix the transform property:
http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Plunker version: http://plnkr.co/edit/HYJ9XJ8rAc3cgVI0uKFe?p=preview

**The second layered image (absolute-positioned) should fit the size and the position of the first**

Add `left: 0` and `right: 0` to your absolute positioned element.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will use it for hover, it suits it very well, compatibility is not an issue for cosmetic effects.

Comment: Still, I not resolved `width:90%` with absolute-positioned image, I guess additional container with padding would work instead but it would be fine to know where I messed up this time.

Comment: I don't understand what your issue is, your post only said you had one issue "(not ok)"

Comment: I've updated the question to state this explicitly. It is absolute-positioned image in my plunker (the one that appears left-aligned). `width:90%` causes it, it looks fine with `width:100%`

Comment: That's awesome, thank you. I wouldn't come up to this by my own.